# How can I create a dictionary with a function,and add it to a list?

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.7

Let me put it this way: I want to have a book, for which the pages (the dictionaries) are created by a function, and the pages themselves can be referenced by a given name; so that when I want to print the contents of specifc page, I can call it by the given reference name.

Example:

The name of the book is called "list_of_customers" : 
`list_of_customers=[]`

In `list_of_customers` I want to have a dictionary which will hold the data for each customer:`customer1={"name": "John","Items": 10}`

`customer1` will be in `list_of_customers`. But how would the function be structured in order to make a `customer2`,3 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an array to represent book you can't use the reference name directly to access the page but you can use technique call inverted index. An inverted index is an index data structure storing a mapping from content, such as words or numbers, to its locations in a document or a set of documents.

Assumptions

1. One page has multiple references
2. One reference has multiple pages

```
book = [] //array of pages
page = {} //Dict return by some function 

reverence_index = {
   'reference1': [1,2,4,5,6], // reference1 will have multiple page indexes 
   'reference2': [3,6,7]
}
```

So we can access the related pages for a given reference using the reverence_index.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary elements of which are dictionaries themselves. E.g.

```py
book = {}
book['page1'] = somefunction(args1)
book['page2'] = somefunction(args2)
```